# What does it mean? picture related

Tags: translation

Didn't find any mentioning about this sound. Is it laughing?

[image: pic]

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: you should provide more context ,it will be much easier for others to help you

Comment: Context is simple, a human makes this sound. Nothing else

Answer (score 1):

I believe that says 「クイッ」?
Japanese people use a lot of onomatopoeias and a lot of them doesnt even make sense. Without context, I can take this as a laughing sound or maybe when something smooth like a plate is getting scrubbed.

Comment: Onomatoeias is what I thought but didn't know the name. Thank you for pointing.
Found out this can be  *tug* or *turn* sound, like a turn head to signal something. Other topic says that ッ is a choked sound, so it making this sound softer, I guess. My guess it's sound of heavy body movement because source of this sound is gigantic.